# Understanding why $http is passed in to angular.js controller

Tags: angularjs

I was just goinh through an angular.js tutorial HERE and basically the following script is built in the tutorial:

```
angular.module('APP',[]).
            controller('theController' , ['$scope' , '$http' , function( $scope , $http ){
                $http.jsonp('http://www.filltext.com/?rows=30&id={index}&fname={firstName}&lname={lastName}&sales={randomNumberRange|100to2000}&bonus={randomNumberRange|200to600}&callback=JSON_CALLBACK').success(function(data){
                            $scope.users = data 
                    });    
                    $scope.totalMoney = function(user) {
                        return user.sales + user.bonus;
                    }
            }]).filter('initials' , function(){
               return function(text){
                   var names = text.split(' '),
                       holder = [];
                   angular.forEach(names , function(item){
                      holder.push(item.substring(0,1) + '.'); 
                   });
                   return holder.join('');
               }
            });
```

, the tut is actually about how to create a custom filter, and thats quite well explained. but i don't quite understand the `'$http'` being passed in, can somebody explain that please ?

Comment: It's passed in because it's being used in the controller

Comment: @kodvin i absolutely know that already !!

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're trying to understand the "injection" concept. There's a tutorial here on the specifics: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

But, in brief. Before Angular executes most methods, it scans them to see what they're looking for, and then it passes those arguments to the method in the anticipated order.

Normally in javascript, you have to know what order arguments are passed in and then you name them accordingly. But with Angular, it's inverse. It anticipates what you're asking for and gives you what you want.

The **array format** being used is called "Dependency Annotation" and is an Angular-specific format. It is only there to make minification work. Without minification, you can do the following and it'll also work:

```
angular.module('APP',[]).
  controller('theController', function($scope , $http){
      $http.jsonp('http://www.filltext.com/?rows=30&id={index}&fname={firstName}&lname={lastName}&sales={randomNumberRange|100to2000}&bonus={randomNumberRange|200to600}&callback=JSON_CALLBACK').success(function(data){
                  $scope.users = data 
          });    
          $scope.totalMoney = function(user) {
              return user.sales + user.bonus;
          }
  }).filter('initials' , function(){
     return function(text){
         var names = text.split(' '),
             holder = [];
         angular.forEach(names , function(item){
            holder.push(item.substring(0,1) + '.'); 
         });
         return holder.join('');
     }
  });
```

Comment: what is `$scope` and `$http` in angular ?? what are these `things` called

Comment: I recommend doing an [angular crash course](http://toddmotto.com/ultimate-guide-to-learning-angular-js-in-one-day/) to cover some of the core concepts. Also, search the Angular documentation, it's really helpful. [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) and [`$scope`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope) are well documented